# Discussion Forum Scraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.iimbx.edu.in/dashboard')

user_input = driver.find_element_by_id('login-email')
user_input.send_keys(USERNAME)

user_password = driver.find_element_by_id('login-password')
user_password.send_keys(PASSWORD)

button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login"]/div[4]/button')
button.click()

res = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')


courses_list = box.find_all('h2', {'class':'mycourse_title'})

for a in courses_list:
    for a in courses_list.find_all('a', href=True):
        print(a['href'])
```

**But I am getting error like this:**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-64e553ba2d72> in <module>
     18 
     19 for a in courses_list:
---> 20     for a in courses_list.find_all('a', href=True):
     21         print(a['href'])

AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you already tried to achieve your solution?

Comment: what is the `box` here? no any other declaration of `box` in above code

Comment: `Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?` ?

Comment: Why are you looping `for a in courses_list` twice?

Comment: @Pavan What is the question?

Comment: @Manali Kagathara: That is not box later i find out and replaced it with soup.

Comment: @cricket_007: Hi thank you for your suggestion and that is correct not find_all , it is find() it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chosen_no = int(input('Please enter the Course Number you want to Extract: '))
selectedCourse = 0
i = 0
for course in  coursesDict:
    if course['number'] == chosen_no:
        selectedCourse = course

    i = i+1

print(selectedCourse)
driver.get('https://your_site_url' + selectedCourse['href'])
```

Comment: Perfect sir. It is also working. Thanks for the timely help sir.